# How do I properly align li tags on left/right side?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have this `nav` which has two `ul` tags. I want one of the `ul` to appear on the left side of the screen and the other `ul` to appear on the right side.

I tried using `float: right` on the second, which sort of worked but 1. I don't like using `float`, and 2. It wasn't aligned properly, so the lines were uneven, and not even `line-height` was able to fix it.

I've been messing around with other displays, but nothing I'm trying has worked.

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar__left">
    <li>
      <a href="">Home</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navbar__right">
    <li>
      <a href="">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Login</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

.navbar {
  border: 1px solid black;
  ul {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
  }
  li {
    margin: 0 1em;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to easily achieve the output you are looking for, like below. I converted your SCSS to CSS to have a working example here.

```css
.navbar {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  margin: 0 1em;
  list-style-type: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar__left">
    <li>
      <a href="">Home</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navbar__right">
    <li>
      <a href="">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Login</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```